# How to make Vue app in javascript and make it work in html?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Hi I'm trying to make my Vue app in javascript so it isn't in html. Is there any way how to make it work? I tried this:

In HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="assets/actions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in javascript:

```
const AppNotes = Vue.createApp({
    data: {
        newFormtext: "",
        contents: [
            {title: "First Title", contents: ["content1", "content2", "content3"]}

        ]
    },
    methods: {
        addNewFormEvent() {
            this.titles.push(this.formtext)
        }
    }
})

AppNotes.mount('#content')
```

but it don't work in my html and text is still like {{ content.title }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic template of vuejs 2 using html and javascript, without node.

You must call `Vue` constructor and set the `el` value to some tag id.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#notes-app",
  data: {
    counter: 0
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.counter++;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="notes-app">
  {{ counter }}
  <button v-on:click="increment">increment</button>
</div>
```